# Redirect url's using RewriteRule

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite, drupal7

I had a site, say example.com/drupal running on xampp

I have since changed the DocumentRoot in httpd.conf to /drupal/, so that I could access my site using example.com

But Google has already crawled my site and shows results of the form

example.com/drupal/something

which of course go to 404 pages.

How do I use RewriteRules to redirect

example.com/drupal/something

to

example.com/something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply use the standard Apache `RedirectPermanent` directive instead of bothering with attempting to use the relatively expensive Rewrite engine.

Check out http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It led me to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch (RedirectMatch), and I used the rule like   RedirectMatch 301 ^/drupal/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about referencing that directive too.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^/drupal$ /
RewriteRule ^/drupal/(.*) /$1
```